# Parse exact format not valid

Tags: c#, string, file, date, datetime

I need to parse a string and convert it to DateTime . I have the following snippet :

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fichier))
{
    while ((item = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] table = item.Split('\t');
        string _date = table[2];
        pointages.Add(DateTime.ParseExact(_date,"yyyy-MM-dd-hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None));
    } 
}
```

**Edit2**

the content of the file:

```
917          2014-06-24-07:43:47     Finger
```

the string  `_date =2014-06-24-07:43:47`. When i execute the program i got this exception:
`String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

**Edit**

When i added a line before like this :

```
  while ((item = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] table = item.Split('\t');
                    string _date = table[2];
                    _date ="2014-06-24-07:43:47";
                    pointages.Add(DateTime.ParseExact(_date,"yyyy-MM-dd-hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None));
                }
```

It Works!!!

- What are the reasons of this error?
- How can i fix it?

Comment: What is the value of _date? Obviously it's not a valid date, as the error message tells you. Did you debug?

Comment: Your sample string works for me, so it must be a different string. Use the debugger. Maybe it is actually using 24h clock like `17:43:47`, then you need `HH` instead of `hh`.

Comment: My guess is that you *actually* want `HH` rather than `hh`, and that your error string was something like "2014-06-24-15:43:47". If you control the format, by the way, I'd use a `T` (or space) to separate the date and time, rather than a -.

Comment: your _date has to be a different value, The value you provided works just fine..

Comment: See your example working here: http://ideone.com/iIFMpS

Comment: @Lamloumi: your edit is pointless, it just shows what we're already telling you: your sample string works. So either it is a completely different string because your data is corrupt, or some strings are in 24h clock (my and Jon's guess). Use the debugger, set a breakpoint at the error-line. You can also use `DateTime.TryParseExact` and stop the execution if it returns `false` which means that the string could not be parsed.

Comment: i used the debugger and it is the same string!!

Comment: @Lamloumi: That's impossible. Maybe it has leading or trailing spaces, use `_date = _date.Trim()`.

Comment: When i added the `Trim()` it works!!!!!! but i don't see any spaces @TimSchmelter , why this happens?

Comment: @Lamloumi: `Trim` removes not only spaces but all kind of characters that belong to `SpaceSeparator`, `LineSeparator` or `ParagraphSeparator` caregories. So maybe it was a tab or whatever. Have a look at the remarks section of [`Char.IsWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace.aspx) which is used by [`String.Trim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks :) please put your last comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample string works for me, so it must be a different string. Use the debugger. Maybe it is actually using 24h clock like `17:43:47`, then you need `HH` instead of `hh`.

> You: no, it is really the string i've posted.

That's impossible. Maybe it has leading or trailing spaces, use `Trim` first:

```
_date = _date.Trim();
```

`Trim` removes not only spaces but all kind of characters that belong to `SpaceSeparator`, `LineSeparator` or `ParagraphSeparator` caregories. So maybe it was a tab or whatever. Have a look at the remarks section of [`Char.IsWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace.aspx) which is used by [`String.Trim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Side-Note: if you don't know if the format is valid you could use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead which doesn't raise an exception but returns `false` if a string could not be parsed to `DateTime`:

```
bool couldBeParsed = DateTime.TryParseExact(
    _date.Trim(), 
    "yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.None,
    out dt);
```